# PSQL: select all assets that have all of given list of associated objects ids

Tags: sql, performance, optimization, postgresql

Suppose we have a standard has and belongs to many association between products and categories
product_categories table consists of product_id and category_id pairs.

We have list of category_id's and need to select all products that belongs to all these categories.

The best approach that came to my mind is to have multiple *EXISTS()* in where clause conjuncted by *AND* at programming language level:

```
SELECT * FROM products p WHERE 
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM product_categories pc 
   WHERE pc.product_id = p.id AND pc.category_id = {first_id}) AND
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM product_categories pc 
   WHERE pc.product_id = p.id AND pc.category_id = {second_id}) AND ...
```

*EXISTS* is fast in Postgres 8.4 so no performance issue with this approach.

But I wounder is there any more elegant of doing this type of queries?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM products p WHERE 
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM product_categories pc 
       WHERE pc.product_id = p.id AND pc.category_id = {first_id}) 
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM products p WHERE 
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM product_categories pc 
       WHERE pc.product_id = p.id AND pc.category_id = {second_id}) 
INTERSECT
....
```

Comment: Because it will find products that have at least one of given category_id but not all of them.

Comment: @Bogdan, missed that. Ok, you can try INTERSECT for such cases

Comment: How it should look like with INTERSECT?